# DAX - Summarise with filters

Tags: formula, dax

Anyone knows how can I do this fromula ?
It is giving me an error.  Tks.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mt8q2.png)

Comment: Similar post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62420180

Comment: In general, please share code text instead of images of code. It's also a good idea to explain what you are trying to do and what the error you are getting says.

Comment: It doen´t work, because I need an aggregation, not a filter. I try to find some post related, but I´m not finding any.
It say "Query is not a valid table expression or it needs a base table"

Comment: It is an aggregation but you'd SUMX `t` instead of MAXX `DateValue`.